# Array sorting by two parameters

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm having a little difficulty with the array.sort. I have a class and this class has two fields, one is a random string the other one is a random number. If i want to sort it with one parameter it just works fine. But i would like to sort it with two parameters. The first one is the SUM of the numbers(from low to high), and THEN if these numbers are equal by the random string that is give to them(from low to high).

Can you give some hint and tips how may i can "merge" these two kinds of sort?

```
Array.Sort(Phonebook, delegate(PBook user1, PBook user2)
        { return user1.Sum().CompareTo(user2.Sum()); });
        Console.WriteLine("ORDER");

        foreach (PBook user in Phonebook)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(user.name);
        }
```

That's how i order it with one parameter.

Comment: Can you share some code examples for what you are doing that is working and what you have tried that has not worked?

Comment: Sum of what numbers? Each item only has one number, right?

Comment: google linq join queries and order by - there's a hint

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i think this is what you are after:

```
sourcearray.OrderBy(a=> a.sum).ThenBy(a => a.random)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the general algorithm that you'll use for comparing multiple fields in a `CompareTo` method:

```
public int compare(MyClass first, MyClass second)
{
    int firstComparison = first.FirstValue.CompareTo(second.SecondValue);

    if (firstComparison != 0)
    {
        return firstComparison;
    }
    else
    {
        return first.SecondValue.CompareTo(second.SecondValue);
    }
}
```

However, LINQ does make the syntax for doing this much easier, allowing you to only write:

```
Phonebook = Phonebook.OrderBy(book=> book.Sum())
            .ThenBy(book => book.OtherProperty)
            .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in-place by using a custom `IComparer<PBook>`. The following should order your array as per your original code, but if two sums are equal it should fall back on the random string (which I've called `RandomString`):

```
public class PBookComparer : IComparer<PBook>
{
    public int Compare(PBook x, PBook y)
    {
        // Sort null items to the top; you can drop this
        // if you don't care about null items.
        if (x == null)
            return y == null ? 0 : -1;
        else if (y == null)
            return 1;

        // Comparison of sums.
        var sumCompare = x.Sum().CompareTo(y.Sum());
        if (sumCompare != 0)
            return sumCompare;

        // Sums are the same; return comparison of strings 
        return String.Compare(x.RandomString, y.RandomString);
    }
}
```

You call this as

```
Array.Sort(Phonebook, new PBookComparer());
```

You *could* just do this inline but it gets a bit hard to follow:

```
Array.Sort(Phonebook, (x, y) => { 
    int sc = x.Sum().CompareTo(y.Sum());
    return sc != 0 ? sc : string.Compare(x.RandomString, y.RandomString); });
```

... Actually, that isn't too bad, although I *have* dropped the `null` checks.